# PyTorch error with expected object of scaler float but instead got object of scaler Long

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pytorch

So I am following a course on Udemy (artificial intelligence a-z)and I have run into an error where it says the following:
return map(lambda x: Variable(torch.cat(x, 0)), samples)
 RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for sequence element 1 in sequence argument at position #1 'tensors'

The element also seems to change each time so I don't know where the problem could be
can someone please help me solve this?

I have already tried to modify the previous line (samples) to see if that's what I need to convert to Long but it doesn't work, unless in doing it wrong

Included lines 43-45 of ai.py

```
def sample(self, batch_size):
    samples = zip(*random.sample(self.memory, batch_size))
    return map(lambda x: Variable(torch.cat(x, 0)), samples)
```

Included lines 74-87 of ai.py (whats calling the sample method)

```
def update(self, reward, new_signal):
    new_state = torch.Tensor(new_signal).float().unsqueeze(0)
    self.memory.push((self.last_state, new_state, 
    torch.LongTensor([int(self.last_action)]), 
    torch.tensor([self.last_reward])))
    action = self.select_action(new_state)
    if len(self.memory.memory) > 100:
        batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action = 
        self.memory.sample(100)
    self.learn(batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action)
    self.last_action = action
    self.last_state = new_state
    self.last_reward = reward
    self.reward_window.append(reward)
    if len(self.reward_window) > 1000:
        del self.reward_window[0]
    return action
```

To be honest, I expect the rest of the program to run, but it always seems to crash here, sorry I can't be more specific on what I expect, that's because I don't know it's my first time making a proper AI

Comment: I don't know what the code isn't formatting

Comment: Just try `torch.cat(x, 0.)` instead. It doesn't like the `int`.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat, you need to have the same type for all tensors in your `x` in `return map(lambda x: Variable(torch.cat(x, 0)), samples)`. But you mixed types of tensors in

```
self.memory.push((self.last_state, new_state, 
    torch.LongTensor([int(self.last_action)]), 
    torch.tensor([self.last_reward])))
```

So that's why it threw an exception.